# Redirect page inside RadPanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radpanelbar

I have two forms that must be displayed side by side.

When I click on the row it must be redirect to the RadPanel

```
Response.Redirect("Url.aspx");
```

here is my code for radpanel.

```
<telerik:RadSplitter ID="RadSplitter1" runat="server">
     <telerik:RadPane ID="RadPane1" runat="server" ContentUrl="Form4.aspx">
                <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="AjaxPanel1" runat="server" Height="100%">  
           </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
     </telerik:RadPane>
</telerik:RadSplitter>
```

Everytime when I click on a row. It will just redirect to the page.
but not inside the radpanel?

How will i do this?

NOTE: It must be displayed within the RadPanel

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have a content url assigned but also have inner content (the ajaxpanel)

```
string newURL= "otherForm.aspx";
you can change the RadPane1.ContentUrl = newURL;
```

...that should work as is but you'll need to remove the ajaxpanel.